# Trouble with On-Behalf-Of flow with standalone Blazor WASM, AAD, .NET Core 6 Web API calling MS Graph

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a standalone Blazor WASM site (client), a separate .NET 6 web API (server) with protected endpoints and I'm trying to call MS Graph from the API.

I've read just about every article I could find on the configuration required to make this work and I'm stuck with the incremental consent failing. I get the following error when trying to access a server API which uses MS Graph:

> Error acquiring a token for a downstream web API - MsalUiRequiredException message is: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '[redacted]' named '[redacted]'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

### Configuration...

1. Created AAD app for Web API (server), added secret for Graph configuration, set the app URI and created `access_as_user` scope under "Expose an API" in AAD.
2. Added the client ID (from the following step) to the `knownClientApplications` section in the manifest for the server app registration in AAD.
3. For API Permissions I added Graph scopes `User.Read`, `User.Read.All`, and `Group.Read.All` and provided admin consent in the AAD UI.
4. Configured `appsettings.json` in the API to add the Graph API `BaseUrl` and above scopes from step 2 along with the correct AzureAD domain, `TenantId`, `ClientId`, and `ClientSecret` values for MSAL to function.
5. Configured MSAL on the server:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

6. Created AAD app for Blazor WASM, used SPA auth w/redirect to `https://localhost:7014/authentication/login-callback` and set the API permissions to `api://[redacted]/access_as_user` only.
7. Created custom authorization message handler according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

```cs
public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, NavigationManager navigation) : base(provider, navigation)
{
  ConfigureHandler(
      authorizedUrls: new[]
      {
          "https://localhost:7069"
      },
      scopes: new[]
      {
          "api://[redacted]/.default"
      });
}
```

8. Configured MSAL on the client:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
  builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
  options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://[redacted]/.default");
  options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
}
```

9. Set up named HTTP client on the Blazor client with custom message handler:

```cs
var baseAddress = builder.Configuration["PublicApiUrl"];

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("PublicApi", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("PublicApi"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

### What works...

1. I can authenticate as an AAD user to the Blazor client.
2. I can access protected endpoints (using policy-based authorization) hosted on the server which don't have a dependency on MS Graph.

### Questions...

1. Following [this article's guidance](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access#handling-incremental-consent-or-conditional-access-in-web-apps) about incremental consent, specifically the "Static permissions" section, I would assume granting admin consent for Graph on the server's app registration would suffice?
2. All of the documentation showing Blazor WASM with a protected API calling a protected API (Graph) assume the Blazor client is also hosted by the API server. Is it even possible to use on-behalf-of flow in my case? If it was hosted I could see the API calling the Blazor navigation subsystem to perform an incremental consent redirect but when they're separated, I can only imagine the static permissions is the way to go.
3. Is it necessary to set the `DefaultAccessTokenScopes` in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is use of the `AddMicrosoftGraph` method when the API application is being built.

The `GraphServiceClient` created by `AddMicrosoftGraph` will have default access to **delegated permissions** which are assigned to *users* as opposed to **application permissions** which are assigned to *applications*. This is why the **MsalUiRequiredException** is being thrown which is usually resolved by prompting the user to login.

You can read more about **delegated** vs **application** permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types).

What you can do instead is use the `AddMicrosoftGraphAppOnly` method to create a `GraphServiceClient` that will use credentials specific to your API to retrieve the relevant data needed from the Microsoft Graph API.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraphAppOnly(
        authenticationProvider => new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

So long as you have the relevant settings and secrets provided in the **AzureAd** section of your `appsettings.json` file the `GraphServiceClient` injected into your application should now be able to access the data you need.

You can read more about app configuration with the **AzureAd** settings in your `appsettings.json` file [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore).